# What does double colon in laravel means

Tags: php, laravel-5

Example :

```
Auth::guard($guard)->guest()
```

I dont get what double colon (::) notation means in laravel framework. from http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php I learn that it stand for scope resolution operator to access static, constant and overridden properties or methods of a class. but from laravel I learn that `Auth` means the alias for class facade so I need an explanation of the example above especially `guard(parameter)->guest()` means.
I'm still new to php and now learning laravel framework for my back-end.

Comment: The double colon has no different meaning in Laravel. You are accessing the static method `guard` of the class Auth and pass a parameter to it.

Comment: If you're learning PHP, I suggest you to learn and keep a clear difference between PHP itself and a framework. A framework like Laravel does a lot of stuff behind scenes that you will miss (and confuse you like this) if you try to learn PHP by learning a framework.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois thnks for nice answer sir, so i'm accessing static **guard** method from auth class. and how about the guest() method? why it can be accessed from the guard() method sir? thnks again before

Comment: The static method `guard` returns a class instance, I have no idea which class, but you can easily find that out by either reading the docs or dumping the return of `guard` (by using `dd` (helper function of Laravel)).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`::` Scope Resolution Operator

`::` is called as `scope resolution operator` (AKA Paamayim Nekudotayim). This operator is used to refer the scope of some block or program context like classes, objects, namespace and etc. For this reference an identifier is used with this operator to access or reproduce the code inside that scope.

[Reference](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php)

`Auth::guard($guard)->guest()` : In this line you are using the **guard()** method of static class `Auth`. To use the function of a static class we use `::` Scope Resolution Operator.

Comment: Also called `Paamayim Nekudotayim` and is preferred by the PHP parser (especially for fatal errors) :P

Comment: in laravel when i open Auth class i only see getFacadeAccessor method that returning auth string sir. how guard() and guest() method can be linked to Auth class sir thnk you.

Comment: @Jsnow now one is sir here, we all are on same level. Check this: https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Auth/Guard.html

Comment: thank your mr. @MayankPandey for the guide i will study it now

Answer (score 5):

You are likely encountering this as a way of accessing a static method or property of a class.

For example:

```
class Foo
{
    public static function bar()
    {
      return "bar";
    }
}

Foo::bar // access the bar method without instantiating the Foo class.
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically its know as

```
Scope resolution operator (::)
```

Simply it is token which allow access to static, constant and overridden properties of method of a class

Example- in laravel we call model like this

`User::select('name')->get()->toArray()`;