# What is the meaning of this '::' double colon sign in laravel

Tags: laravel

```
public function up() { 
    Schema::create('table', function (Blueprint $table) { 
    $table->bigIncrements('id'); $table->timestamps(); 
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does double colon in laravel means](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39198357/what-does-double-colon-in-laravel-means)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access Static properties using PHP object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17107869/access-static-properties-using-php-object)

Answer (score 6):

I'ts the way PHP allows you to access properties, static, constant and methods from a Class.

In this case you are accessing the `create` method from the `Schema` Class

For more info: [Docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php)

A little example from the PHP docs:

```
<?php
class MyClass {
    const CONST_VALUE = 'A constant value';
}

$classname = 'MyClass';
echo MyClass::CONST_VALUE;
?>
```

Comment: Glad i could help :)

Answer (score 0):

PHP Scope resolution operator

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php